# How to use ref to store a document correctly in mongodb - mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to store a ref of a user model in my users  - followers Array:

The model looks something like this:

```
User = require('../models/user.js');
ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

User = new Schema({

followers: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
```

Now I am trying to store every time a user follows a user like so:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: myId}, { $addToSet:  {followers: user._id,
```

However, this only stores the string and not the whole user object? Is that how it is suppose to be? If so, then to grab it out the rest of the info do I just need to do a populate query?

If it is suppose to store the whole object then does it update as well as the object gets updated?

Answer (score 1):

I was going to remove the question as I figured it out, but I see that people up-voted it so to help them out, I shall post my discoveries.

Apparently it will just store the id, and to then call it I used a basic populate call on it like so:

```
User
.findOne({ _id: myId })
.populate('followers', '_id name count') // 
.exec(function (err, doc) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);


})
```